# R: Counting the number of matches between multiple data frames

Tags: r, unique

I want to find the number of matches based on ID of unique matches within multiple data.frames

Data looks like this:

```
df1: KeyID
       x
       x
       y
       y
       z

df2: KeyID
       x
       x
       x
       z
       z

df3: KeyID
       x
       y
       y
       z
```

I want to count the number of unique matches between data frames.

output would look like this:
 2

Since x and z are the only matches between the two sets.

I have done this but want to know if there is a faster way:

```
df1.2 <- df2[df2$KeyID %in% df1$KeyID,]
length(unique(df1.2$KeyID))
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Wouldn't this just be `sum(unique(df1$KeyID) %in% unique(df2$KeyID)))`? Actually now that I think about it more, you might need to wrap `as.character` around them if they're factors.

Comment: @BondedDust only if position doesn't matter... as it stands now, it is hard to tell what the asker wants...

Comment: Position does not matter...just want to know how many of KeyIDs are in both data frames, or in dfs 1,2,3 and so on.

Comment: You mentioned multiple datasets/vectors.If more than two: `Reduce("intersect", listofvectors)`

Comment: @akrun Is reduce part of a package?

Comment: @CoryB It's in the base package, but be careful of capitalization, the command is `Reduce`.

Comment: @tkmckenzie  I tried Reduce however it is not happy : Reduce("intersect",PCS$KeyID,Spr.1104$KeyID)

Comment: @CoryB You need to put the vectors in a list first, see the edit to my answer below.

Comment: @tkmckenzie Fixed it!  length(Reduce("intersect",list(PCS$KeyID,Spr.1104$KeyID)))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do set intersection with `intersect`:

```
v1 <- c("x", "x", "y", "y", "z")
v2 <- c("x", "x", "x", "z", "z")
intersect(v1, v2)
# [1] "x" "z"
length(intersect(v1, v2))
# [1] 2
```

Edit: Adapting for the question edit, as per akrun's suggestion, if there are multiple vectors,

```
v1 <- c("x", "x", "y", "y", "z")
v2 <- c("x", "x", "x", "z", "z")
v3 <- c("x", "y", "y", "z")
vector.list <- list(v1, v2, v3)

Reduce("intersect", vector.list)
# [1] "x" "z"
```

Comment: Again, only if position doesn't matter.

Comment: @CoryB See akrun's comment above.