# Comparing a vector with another one

Tags: r

Given two data tables with these columns:

```
dt1<- c("name")
dt2<-c("name", "alternative_name_1", "alternative_name_2", "ethnicity")
```

I want to find out which names are common in these two data tables.
I know that I can use the merge function to merge my two data tables by common names. However, at the same time, I also need to compare the alternative names of my bigger data table with the names of my smaller data table and see if they match. How can I do that?

Comment: Provide a reproducible example and show what the desired output is. see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: read `?intersect()`

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! To improve your experience, read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) an [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) question. You should also take a look at the [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). To lean more about how Stack Overflow works, [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R: Counting the number of matches between multiple data frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25045496/r-counting-the-number-of-matches-between-multiple-data-frames)

Answer (score 0):

library(tidyverse)

## or

library(dplyr)

intersect(dt1,dt2)

this should return common occurrence from the two data frames

Answer (score 0):

One can try as following:

```
> dt1==dt2
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
> intersect(dt1, dt2)
[1] "name"
```